# Woes with copy operation and extended properties in EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, extended-properties

I am tasked with bidirectioanlly synching contact folders in two mailboxes with a service.
Please bear with me, as this is the first time I'm using EWS in C#.

In order to uniquely identify items and track changes for synching, I am utilizing `SyncFolderHierarchy()` for subfolders and `SyncFolderItems()` for items in each subfolder, while tracking the syncstate.

Since the folder/item IDs are depdendent on the mailbox, on initial sync, as well as on Create operations, I am tagging synched items with an extended property via `Item.SetExtendedProperty()`

This works really well, but I have run into a caveat.

When a user copies and pastes a folder or contact in Outlook, it also copies the unique ID (extended property), making it not-so-unique anymore.
In that case, I now have two items in a mailbox with the same "unique" ID, and now have an ambiguous match for the item.

Basically:

1. `SyncFolderItems()` is invoked, and sync state saved
2. Item is tagged with unique ID if it doesn't have one
3. User copies and pastes the item
4. `SyncFolderItems()` is invoked (with previous sync state), returns a `Create` event for user-copied item
5. Item that is created already has a unique ID

Now, one might argue just overwrite the unique ID for an item in a create event.

**However, this leads to the following issue:**

When I sync a new item from mailbox A into mailbox B, I also create an item.
Once `SyncFolderItems()` on mailbox A is now invoked, I also retrieve a Create event for my own item, which in this case legitimately already has a unique ID assigned that must not be overwritten.

I basically see two options:

- Somehow prevent this extended property from being copyable
- Prevent EWS from sending a create for an item I created myself.
  *I am aware I can ignore ItemIDs in a `SyncFolderItems()` call, but I am not sure how I should track the item IDs across calls because they may change according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-identifiers-in-exchange)*

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to approach this differently or implement either option??

Comment: Direct synching between two databases requires that the keys are actually unique. As you said, they are not doing that properly. So you need a 3rd Database. Some file format or other where you and *only* you gave out the primary keys. That way you got control and can maintain that each key is actually unique.

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about keeping track in a sqlite. However, on copy, Exchange would still duplicate the unique key I assigned to an item, or in database terms, violate that constraint. So keeping the key in a third place would still result in an ambiguous match :/

Comment: @Christopher Just to clarify: You mean keep all sync IDs ever issued, and when a change event comes with a syncID never seen before, ignore it? I'm currently thinking about caveats and might try this out...

Comment: My point is to ignore the key in Exchange. It is not reliable and propably never will be. You might even be missusing a field that was not intended for primary keys. Have a 3rd databsae. Let **it** be the authority on the state of of both endpoints.

Comment: @Christopher Yes, ok, so let me ask: it seems the ItemID/FolderID is not guaranteed to stay the same. So if I store it in a master database, how can I match an item to the master database on a `SyncFolderItems()` call? The code example at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ee693003(v%3Dexchg.80) only mentions "Todo: Update / Delete / ... item on client" and `ic.ItemId.UniqueId`: Is the ItemID (or uniqueID) here guranteed to match something seen before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Exchange id should really be *your* unique id as well. It is really not worth it to keep your id on the item itself - firstly, that requires a modification of that item (and that will generate a change event even though it was you who caused the change), and secondly, as you have already noticed, you can end up with duplicates or triplicates of the same item.

It is even worse for the appointments - each incoming appointment update causes Outlook to recreate the appointment, causing a new id to be used and wiping out your custom property.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Dmitry. I was just wary of using it because the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/ews-identifiers-in-exchange states `Don't assume that your ID will always be valid if you need to retrieve the item at a later time`. Of course I would much rather use this ID than finicking around with a custom property! So you say the ID in a ChangeState will be something seen before?

Comment: As long as the item is there, you should be able to use it. If not, you can assume that the item was deleted / recreated /moved to a different mailbox / etc.

Comment: Thanks. I am currently working on the implementation and will report / accept next week if it works!

Comment: Mapping both side's ItemIds and FolderIds to each other in a database is of course tedious, but appears to work well.